# VM Workstation Networking

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I setup a virtual lab on my windows 7 laptop

my windows 7 laptop is getting ip address from my wireless connection.
ie. 192.168.1.100

My virtual lab 
My Virtual DC I use 192.168.2.1
My Virtual member server is 192.168.2.2

I am able to communicate between all servers on my virtual pc's
However, I would like to connect from my virtual lab to outside world using my windows 7 physical laptop.

I tried using NAT, bridge host only all but so for no success.

Please can you someone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason you cannot access outside is your static IPs. In bridged mode, you need to use 192.168.1.x range (which I think you do not want). In NAT mode, you should use the range setup in your VM Manager's NAT settings (safest bet is to set every VM in DHCP mode, unless you want to experiment with TCP/IP setup).

Now, here are the two descriptive alternatives:

1. I assume you assign virtual lab IPs statically. There are many ways to get this done. The simplest is to have all of the VM's in NAT mode and making sure that your virtual machine manager NATs the same IP range (192.168.2.x as you have done it), alternatively, you an set all of the virtual machines in DHCP mode).
2. The other way is to add another network interface to the DC and put it into bridged or NAT mode with DHCP and then run routing service on the DC so that the packets are routed out. Note that in this case, you configure all the VMs in private networking. You would then need to set the gateway for all other VM's to be the DC (I would run a DHCP server on DC and put all the VMs, except for DC, in DHCP mode).

Note that you need to set a name server in places you set up things manually, or in your DHCP servers, for which, I suggest something like 8.8.4.4